# Complex sorting of XML using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, linq

I've tried to find a solution for my problem, but my knowledge in this area (Linq, XML) is rather limited. :(
've found a [simular construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922180/sort-xmldocument-using-linq), but I need a litte bit more complex way of sorting.

Consider the Following XML document:

```
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <Table>
            <Trans>
                <B>1</B>
                <A>3</A>
                <C>5</C>
            </Trans>
            <Trans>
                <D>1</D>
                <A>6</A>
                <C>3</C>
            </Trans>
            <Trans>
                <A>1</A>
                <C>3</C>
                <B>5</B>
            </Trans>
        </Table>
    </Body>
<Envelope>
```

Is there any way I can sort the elements inside <Trans> using C#/Linq, or do I have to break up all <Trans> elements and sort them one by one?

**Update**
I have a file and this is what I'm tring to accomplish. ;)

```
<Envelope>
    <Body>
       <Table>
           <Trans>
               <A>3</A>
               <B>1</B>
               <C>5</C>
           </Trans>
           <Trans>
               <A>6</A>
               <C>3</C>
               <D>1</D>
           </Trans>
           <Trans>
               <A>1</A>
               <B>5</B>
               <C>3</C>
           </Trans>
       </Table>
   </Body>
<Envelope>
```

Comment: Is the idea to come up with a new XML document, or just an in-memory representation?

Comment: Do you mean change the order they appear in the XML file? (In which case, why do you want to do this?)

Comment: I think he means that instead of `<D>1</D><A>6</A><C>3</C>` he wants to sort it into `<A>6</A><C>3</C><D>1</D>` in alphabetic order regardless of the integer values.

Comment: Matthew, you're right, that's what I'm trying to accomplish.
Jon, it's a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(....);
foreach(var trans in xDoc.Descendants("Trans"))
{
    trans.ReplaceAll( trans.Elements().OrderBy(x=>x.Name.LocalName));
}

string newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

Comment: This gives me this error? I'm guessing I'm missing some reference? 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found

Comment: Have you included `System.Linq` and `System.Xml.Linq` ?

Comment: @Rowdy Right click on the red underlined variable. Right click, then choose resolve - this will adding missing references for you, provided they are referenced or in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache).

Comment: Thanks, I'd already added those.. Just a small problem, xDoc.Descendants("Trans") does not return *anything*? The element is in the document; I can see it if I evealuate it in the Debugger... :/
At first I thought it could be because there wass al class attribute (<Trans class="entity">) but removing it did not give me any results. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Rowdy.nl `xDoc.Descendants("Trans")` returns `IEnumerable<XElement>` which should be enumerated to get the result(e.g foreach). You may also try to append `.ToArray()` to materialize it.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what exactly you want to do (process them in order, or reorder the XML?) and on what exactly you mean "sort" (sort by tag name? sort by value?).

If you just want to process them in order, this is how you can sort all elements inside each `<Trans>` by value (`<D>1</D>` before `<A>6</A>`):

```
XDocument doc = /* load up your XML */

var sorted = from trans in doc.Descendants("Trans")
             select trans.Children().OrderBy(c => int.Parse(c.Value)).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, here's how to order by tag name (`<A>6</A>` before `<D>1</D>`):

```
var sorted = from trans in doc.Descendants("Trans")
             select trans.Children().OrderBy(c => c.Name.LocalName).ToArray();
```

With the above, `sorted` will be an enumerable collection of arrays. Each array in the collection represents a `<Trans>`, and each such array holds the children of the `<Trans>` in order.

Comment: Thanks Jon, The alternative method is what I'm trying to accomplish.

If I'm right, I can replace the elements in the original document like this?
doc.Descendants("Trans").Remove();
doc.Element("Trans").Add(sorted);

Comment: @Rowdy.nl: L.B's code does exactly that, you only need to tack on a `.ToArray()` after the `OrderBy` :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna give that a try :)Unfortunatly, I can't vote up bevause I don't have enough reputation... :/