# Sorting xml using linq, but getting a null error?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, visual-studio-2010, sorting

Trying to sort an xml file based on a Time Field (soonest first)...  a snippet of the xml is here: (The element I want to order on is TimeEventStart)

```
<Bookings>
  <Data>
    <BookingDate>2015-03-02T00:00:00</BookingDate>
    <StartBookingDate>2015-03-02T00:00:00</StartBookingDate>
    <RoomDescription>The room</RoomDescription>
    <TimeEventStart>6:00 PM</TimeEventStart>
    <TimeEventEnd>2015-03-02T20:00:00</TimeEventEnd>
    <GroupName>Group Council</GroupName>
    <EventName>Some cool event</EventName>
    <SetupTypeDescription>SPECIAL</SetupTypeDescription>
    <SetupCount>30</SetupCount>
    <ReservationID>64352</ReservationID>
    <EventCoordinator>ERS</EventCoordinator>
    <GroupID>124151</GroupID>
    <VIP xml:space="preserve"> </VIP>
    <VIPEvent>false</VIPEvent>
    <ClosedAllDay>false</ClosedAllDay>
    ....
  </Data>
  <Data>
      ....  more like above ...
  </Data>
</Bookings>
```

First off I was using [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117117/complex-sorting-of-xml-using-linq) as a guide:

```
static void SortFeed(String resMain)
{
    XDocument xmlSorted = XDocument.Parse(resMain);
    foreach (var trans in xmlSorted.Descendants("Data"))
    {
        trans.ReplaceAll(trans.Elements().OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Element("TimeEventStart").Value)).ToArray());
    }
    string newXml = xmlSorted.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Done:");
    Console.WriteLine(newXml);
}
```

This runs but gives an error in the

```
DateTime.Parse(x.Element("TimeEventStart").Value)
```

the error was nullreference exception unhandled.

I think I know what is going on, its looking to sort on TimeEventStart but is finding something else instead, I thought this would just only order by on that element if it found it, I must be mistaken.  Having no experience with Linq (and apparently juggling xml files), I am curious what piece I am missing or if maybe I started my parsing off in the wrong area?
(.Decendants? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going in one level too deep - `trans` is already a `Data` element, you're then ordering the elements *within* `Data`... by a `TimeEventStart` element within each of those subelements... and that doesn't exist, because `TimeEventStart` is a direct element within `Data`. I suspect you want to take out your `foreach` loop:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(resMain);
var root = xmlSorted.Root;
var sortedData = root.Elements
                     .OrderBy(data => DateTime.Parse(data.Element("DateTimeStart").Value))
                     .ToArray();
root.ReplaceAll(sortedData);
```

However, you might still have a problem, due to the value of `DateTimeStart` - you've got just `6:00 PM` which doesn't look like a date/time to me. The `DateTimeEnd` value looks like a proper ISO-8601 date/time... indeed, you could just cast such an `XElement` to `DateTime`, e.g.

```
var sortedData = root.Elements
                     .OrderBy(data => (DateTime) data.Element("DateTimeEnd"))
                     .ToArray();
```

... but that's obviously ordering by the end rather than by the start. If that's *really* what your data looks like, and you really want to order by it, you'll need to think a bit about what it actually means, because it's *not* a date and time.

Comment: You are right, i was preprocessing the date and time and splitting it into two fields.  I will order it first then split the date time.

Comment: I think this worked, can i cast that root var to an XmlDocument then?

Comment: @Codejoy: No, because it's not an `XmlDocument`. It's an `XElement`, because it's the root element.

Comment: Found a nice handy class for helping with this and fixing it up.  Thanks so much!