# Change order of elements in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

here is example of xml:

```
<root>
<something1></something1>
<something2></something2>
<something3></something3>
<important>
<some1>123_random_number</some1><some2>ASD</some2>
</important>
<important>
<some1>456_random_number</some1><some2>FGH</some2>
</important>
<important>
<some1>789_random_number</some1><some2>JKL</some2>
</important>
</root>
```

I need to change order of element , to get xml document like this:

```
<root>
<something1></something1>
<something2></something2>
<something3></something3>
<important>
<some1>789_random_number</some1><some2>JKL</some2>
</important>
<important>
<some1>456_random_number</some1><some2>FGH</some2>
</important>
<important>
<some1>123_random_number</some1><some2>ASD</some2>
</important>
</root>
```

Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance,
P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort XMLDocument using linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922180/sort-xmldocument-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

This was easy, but I am beginner :) 
Here is the answer:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"dataIn.xml");
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);
XmlNodeList elem = doc.GetElementsByTagName("important");

List<string> originalOrder = new List<string>();

foreach (XmlNode tag in elem)
  {
    originalOrder.Add(tag.InnerXml);
  }

int numberOfNodes = elem.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
    elem[i].InnerXml = order[order.Count - 1 - i];
  }
doc.Save(@"dataOut.xml");
```